# Firestore security rules - bitwise operations

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I cant find them in the documentation, are they not available?

I would need XOR & and |

Comment: I hope they implement this feature too. Think it would be great for permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no bitwise operations available in Firestore security rules.  If you have a specific use case that requires this, I suggest explaining that in a feature request filed with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  In the short term, you might be better off making schema changes that don't require bitwise operations.

FYI the API documentation for integers is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Integer). You can see that they just support basic math and comparison operations.

Comment: Will post a feature request. Thanks